# Post Image showing Size In Single.php file

Tags: wordpress

i hope you are doing very well, 
please open this link
https://www.pixelstalk.net/winter-backgrounds/winter-background-for-desktop/
and screen shot link here
http://myprintscreen.com/s/p0bp/49cbf6d290

How can i add this option to showing this height + width and image size in my wordpress single post?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Height & Width:**

Try the following. First, add this piece of code to the template:

```
$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full" );
```

`$image_data` will now return an array containing the url, width, and height ([function reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)). To get width & height, you might do this:

```
$image_width = $image_data[1];
$image_height = $image_data[2];
```

In your specific example, after adding the two pieces of code above to your template, you might do this:

```
echo '<label class="dimension">  '.$image_width.' x '.$image_height.'</label>';
```

**Size:**

```
$image_size = size_format(filesize( get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full" ) ));
```

And in your template, add it like this:

```
echo '<label class="data_size"><strong>Image size: </strong>'.$image_size.'</label>';
```

Comment: Hi Dear, i am new so please give me a full code and tell me which file i add this code like function.php single.php like this plz and thanks.

Comment: full code is available above, and normally `single.php` works for single post but it varies theme to theme so it is not mandatory. You need to locate `<label class="dimension">  1920 x 1200.</label>` & `<label class="data_size"><strong>Image size: </strong>465 KB</label>` it can be in `single.php` or in other theme files

Comment: Hi Dear, all code is working perfect only issue for dimension echo '<label class="dimension">  '.$image_width.' x '.$image_height.'</label>'; how can i set dimension ? plz give me code auto detect full dimension thanks dear

Comment: `$image_width` & `$image_height` variable holds full width and height of the image. What you mean by setting dimension? If it is printing code on frontend then add php tags so it will become `<?php echo '<label class="dimension"> '.$image_width.' x '.$image_height.'</label>'; ?>`

Comment: Hi dear, its code working perfect but not showing image size only showing ' x ' may be little other code or some thing need to change ? echo '<label class="dimension">  '.$image_width.' x '.$image_height.'</label>';
 width and height not showing. how can i change thanks

Comment: Place this piece of code before calling that: `$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full" );` & `$image_width = $image_data[1];
$image_height = $image_data[2];`